# Live Stream with Bottle Python

Tags: python, web, frameworks, bottle

I have a problem with Bottle. My goal is to have a camera feed streamed to my web page. The page is streamed from a server, while camera has different location. I've looked into Gevent etc, but not found any solution yet.

How this kind of streaming should be configured, and eventually where should I look for help?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if Bottle is best option here. Anyway - most people stat with [OpenCV](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html). Then you can use motion JPEG, that is also video, but each frame is treated separately. Please visit [this](http://www.chioka.in/python-live-video-streaming-example/) page to see example.